# Using Z3 on OSX with OCaml

Tags: macos, ocaml, z3

I am trying to use the Z3 Solver on OSX using the OCaml binding. 
When attempting to build and run my solution using 
`ocamlfind ocamlc -o testsat.byte -package Z3 -linkpkg testsat.ml` I am getting an `ocamlfind: Package Z3 not found`.

I have also tried using `ocamlbuild` without the `-package` tag, however then I'm getting an `Unbound Module Z3` error.

I am also having problems installing the z3Overlay library - https://github.com/termite-analyser/z3overlay when trying to install the `z3 dev` portion.

Does anyone know of any fixes, or a stable version that can be used on OSX? My assumptions are that I'm encountering these errors since the build is failing (as can be seen from the official documentation: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3).

I am new to this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should tell us how you installed z3. There's now an opam package for z3 4.6, which works for us (with the caveat that `libz3.so` ends up under `~/.opam`).

Comment: @MartinJambon I used `opam install z3`, and installed all the required dependencies, and my installation was successful (i'm guessing). When i run `opam list` z3, I can see z3 in the list of libraries in opam. 

What I'm trying to do now is clone and build the repository itself. (I'm unsure if I'm doing all the right steps). 
Also, when I executed the command `ocamlfind list` z3 did not show up. Could that be the problem?

Comment: It's common to forget to run `eval $(opam config env)` in the shell before running ocamlfind or other non-opam commands directly. It sets environment variables, including `OCAMLPATH` which tells ocamlfind where to find libraries where opam put them.

Comment: Actually I just checked and `eval $(opam config env)` does not set `OCAMLPATH` with opam 2. Maybe it was the case with opam 1.2. Not sure anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library and package names are case sensitive, and the package name of the z3 bindings is `z3` not `Z3`. You can always query for available packages using `ocamlfind list`.

```
ocamlfind list | grep -i Z3
z3                  (version: 4.6.0.0)
```

So the following command will work as expected

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -o testsat.byte -package z3 -linkpkg testsat.ml
```

There is a small caveat, that Martin mentions in the comments, so you should get another error, that should look like this:

```
libz3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, the package installs `libz3.so`in a location that is not searched, thus you should tell the system linker where to search for the z3 shared object. In Mac OS X, this can be achieved by setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, e.g.,

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`opam config var z3:lib`
```

on GNU/Linux systems the same can be done via the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`opam config var z3:lib`
```